# Compare array of objects: Ramda way

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

There are 2 arrays of objects, the first one is

```
const blocks = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
]
```

and the second one is

```
const containers = [
  { block: { id: 1 } },
  { block: { id: 2 } },
  { block: { id: 3 } },
]
```

I want to take `blocks` array, take each object from that and find if `containers` array has block with such id. So if at least one id not found then I want to break loop and return false, otherwise if all id's found return true.

I've tried to implement this with `.some()` function but I couldn't break loop when id is not found.

I would appreciate if you advise Ramda way to mplement this.

Thank you.

Comment: then you should not use `some`, maybe there is a `all`?

Comment: Do you want all the objects to be same or at least one of them?

Comment: @MaheerAli I want all objects in `blocks` array to have similar blocks in `containers` array

Comment: @appleapple There is `.every()` function and I've alredy implemented with that https://jsfiddle.net/qdagc5yv/ but I don't know if it's a good solution, also want to `Ramda` way :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `R.differenceWith`:

```js
const blocks = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
];

const containers = [
  { block: { id: 1 } },
  { block: { id: 2 } },
  { block: { id: 4 } },
];

const diff = R.differenceWith((x,y) => x.id === y.block.id);
const mismatch = diff(blocks, containers).length > 0;

console.log(mismatch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a non ramda way, you could compare each object with the other items and use a deep check.

```js
const
    deep = id => o =>
        o && typeof o === 'object' && (o.id === id || Object.values(o).some(deep(id))),
    compare = (source, target) => source.every(({ id }) => target.some(deep(id))),
    blocks = [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    containers = [{ block: { id: 1 } }, { block: { id: 2 } }, { block: { id: 3 } }]

console.log(compare(blocks, containers));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `equals()` method.

```js
const blocks = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
]

const containers = [
  { block: { id: 1 } },
  { block: { id: 2 } },
  { block: { id: 3 } },
]

console.log(R.equals(containers.map(x => x.block.id),blocks.map(x => x.id)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to compare objects equality, I just want to compare `id` parameter.

Comment: @CroaToa So you can convert both to array of ids. and then compare. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular Ramda Way<sup>TM</sup>.  Ramda is a library, a toolkit, or in Underscore's description, a toolbelt.  It is built to make a certain style of coding easier to read and write in JS.  But it is not meant to dictate at all how you write your code.

Ramda's biggest goal is to make it easier to build applications through composing functions, ensuring such FP goodies as immutability and referential transparency.

So for this problem, I might start with something like the following:

```js
const hasBlock = (containers) => {
  const ids = containers .map (c => c.block.id)
  return (block) => ids .includes (block.id)
}

const allContained = (containers) => (blocks) => 
  blocks .every (hasBlock (containers) )
```

That latter function can be quickly rewritten using Ramda to

```js
const allContained = (containers) => (blocks) =>
  all(hasBlock(containers), blocks)
```

which simplifies to

```js
const allContained = (containers) => all(hasBlock(containers))
```

and from there to the elegant:

```js
const allContained = compose (all, hasBlock)
```

But I don't see any straightforward simplifications of `hasBlock`.  I might on some days write it as

```js
const hasBlock = (containers, ids = containers .map (c => c.block.id) ) => 
  (block) => ids .includes (block.id)
```

but that's only to satisfy some internal craving for single-expression function bodies, and not for any really good reason.  It doesn't make the code any cleaner, and for some readers might make it more obscure.

So here is where I end up:

```js
const hasBlock = (containers) => {
  const ids = containers .map (c => c.block.id)
  return (block) => ids .includes (block.id)
}

const allContained = compose (all, hasBlock)

const containers = [{block: {id: 1}}, {block: {id: 2}}, {block: {id: 4}}]

console .log (
  allContained (containers) ([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]), //=> false
  allContained (containers) ([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 4}]), //=> true
  allContained (containers) ([{id: 4}, {id: 1}]),          //=> true
  allContained (containers) ([{id: 42}]),                  //=> false
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script><script>
const {compose, all} = R      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with JS/Lodash/Ramda almost same exact way.

JS/Lodash having the same exact methods for `every` and `some` and in Ramda with `all` and `any`:

```js
const blocks = [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 }]
const containers = [{ block: { id: 1 } },{ block: { id: 2 } },{ block: { id: 3 } }]

const blocks2 = [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 }]
const containers2 = [{ block: { id: 4 } },{ block: { id: 2 } },{ block: { id: 3 } }]

let hasAllBlocks = (blks, conts) => 
   blks.every(b => conts.some(c => c.block.id === b.id))

let hasAllBlocksLD = (blks, conts) => 
  _.every(blks, b => _.some(conts, c => c.block.id === b.id))

let hasAllBlocksR = (blks, conts) => 
   R.all(b => R.any(c => c.block.id === b.id, conts), blks)

console.log(hasAllBlocks(blocks, containers))   // true
console.log(hasAllBlocks(blocks2, containers2)) // false

console.log(hasAllBlocksLD(blocks, containers))   // true
console.log(hasAllBlocksLD(blocks2, containers2)) // false

console.log(hasAllBlocksR(blocks, containers))   // true
console.log(hasAllBlocksR(blocks2, containers2)) // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```